# DOES router or linux kernel change the tcp headers and ip headers of packets

Tags: linux, tcp, router, iptables, raw-sockets

I was looking into raw sockets. so I created one raw socket client and other one is server. on two different computers. I am using ISP provided router. so I sent spoofed packet (with iphdr struct's saddr of different computer on same network) from client but when the packet received at the server the source ip in packet's ip header was correct (the real sender address=client address) plus the source port and destination port of tcphdr were something different too (which really didnt make sense). So I assumed that my ISP provided router is doing something funny -- OR I am completely wrong correct if this is a normal ip protocol. if I am correct then what steps should i take to configure my router so it does not mess up with tcp and ip headers of incoming packets plus the sync=1 at sender's end became sync=0 of tcphdr. I am using local IPs plus I am trying to implement tcp using raw socket server. I have configured iptables on server as well with sync allowed on my bounded port

```
  iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport xxxx --syn -j ACCEPT
```

WHat settings do I need to do on server in iptables so my socket incoming packets wont be dropped nor any header be touched so I can get all packets required for tcp to keep coming in. plus what setting do I need to do on router so,if its cause problem then, it wont

Update 1:

after spending some time to the problem I found that one cause could be my kernel tcp stack dropping the incoming sync packets. so I looked around and found that in the tcp stack there is work done to make this happening. So I changed the sysctl.conf in /etc to allow sync packets to come in through by adding or uncommenting this line

```
   net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
```

Then I rebooted the system but still no difference. is it because somehow I have to reload my sysctl.conf file. if this is the case or any related case then please fill in.

Update 2

I have reloaded sysctl.conf after allowing syn packets and now I am getting syn packets from client application. but the destination port different. also along with syn=1, ack=1 is also coming in same packet. is this also something kernel is doing. please explain. as long as I know this is not how tcp works (tcp handshake) and I am connecting from client using stream socket

Comment: Just try to test it without involving your ISP provider. Deploy local bench with two virtual machines and router between them. Then test you raw sockets.

Comment: @red0ct what do u mean by local bench>? is it a virtual  somthing on virtual machine. do u mean create two virtual machines and virtual router between them all on same physical machine?

Comment: Yep, I mean 3 VMs, router in the middle, client and server at the ends. The most common way to troubleshoot something is "from simple to complex".

Comment: @red0ct can I implement custom TCP stack and use it in Linux virtual machine by replacing the pre-included stack with linux with my own stack. how much memory do i need to allocate for this kind of virual linux server? in my physical device my memory is 16 GB plus 64 bit processor

Comment: Sorry, but what the ... does a custom TCP stack have to do with this particular question? How it will help you?
You just deploy 3 regular Linux OS on 3 virtual machines and test your client-server software in this simple conditions. If this will not work as expected then you can try to find out the reason, otherwise there is no problem in your code.

Comment: You really think that implementing custom TCP stack is much more easier than figuring out how it all works on Linux? You didn't even localize the problem, you still don't know, why is it not working as expected.

Comment: @red0ct can you please let me know if tcp_v4_conn_request(...) function is in which file. is it `tcp.c` in `ipv4` in source code I wanna check that out.https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/why-are-linux-kernel-protocol-stacks-dropping-syn-packets_595251 and many others forums tell this is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "in which file"? It is explicitly specified through your link, this is `/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c`. You can find it in [elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1245). Please edit your question to add details, now it is unclear what exactly is your problem.

Comment: @red0ct I am still trying to wrap my head around this problem. I have changed the settings in sysctl.conf to allow sync packets to come in through. but still no difference in outcome. do I have to somehow reload this file. I have rebooted my system still not working. I have uncommented `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1`

Comment: One more time: now it is absolutely unclear what are you trying to do. Edit your question to add details.
*"do I have to somehow reload this file"* - reload to where? I added link, you can just click. What's the problem to click a link?

Comment: I get the feeling you're kidding me. You didn't do what I advised about simple testing with virtual machines, but you keep asking me.

Comment: @red0ct I am uisng kali linux 2020. so on my system its not working(after installation failing to start virtual machine) so I thought to give earlier version a try so before doing this I just thought if I try to do everything before I reinstall any OS

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @red0ct after reloading sysctl.conf I am abled to get sync=1 messages but destination port is still different. also getting ack=1 with syn=1 in same packet. as far as I can tell this is not how tcp works. is it again kernel thats doing something to change destination port and ack=1 in packet contains syn=1

Comment: @red0ct I have posted this. using `virtual machines` at client and server. its similar question.