# tcp client getting different desitination port (client address)in packet at the receiving end C/TCP/RawSockets/Networking/Linux

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, raw-sockets

I am trying to make tcp server using raw sockets. this way I can learn more about tcp. the problem with my tcp server is that I am getting different destination port at receiving end (client's end). the server (source port) is correct but desitination port is different. so my telnet/nc client keep trying to connect. it doesn't get to connected and gives error to client that refused to connect. the problem is I am getting packet with SYN+ACK at destination system but port is not what the source port of client is (I checked it on Client using wireshark) something  is changing the destination port address (client port address) or I am not assignning it correctly at originating server before raw sockets send. I think the problem may be with this line. I am running the code (client and server) **in two virtual machines** Linux on both

```
  temp->dest=tcp->source;
```

`tcp` is the tcp header of received packet at server from client
and `temp->dest` is the tcp client port address in sending packet from server to client

//Following is the main method, it listens to requests

```
    // Packet length
    #define PCKT_LEN 8192


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int sd;
        char buffer[PCKT_LEN];
        int one = 1;
        const int *val = &one;
        memset(buffer, 0, PCKT_LEN);
        sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if(sd < 0)
        {
        perror("socket() error");
        exit(-1);
        }
        else
        printf("socket()-SOCK_RAW and tcp protocol is OK.\n");
        if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one)) < 0)
        {
        perror("setsockopt() error");
        exit(-1);
        }
        else
        printf("setsockopt() is OK\n");
        struct sockaddr_in sa;
        sa.sin_family=AF_INET;
        sa.sin_port=htons(80);
        sa.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
        if(bind(sd,&sa,sizeof (sa))==0){
            printf("Port Bound\n");
        }
        unsigned int count;

        while(1)

        {
             char buffer1[8192];
             struct sockaddr_in saddr;
             int in_len;
            if((recvfrom(sd,buffer1,sizeof (buffer1),0,&saddr,&in_len))!=-1){
               connect1(saddr,buffer1);
               sleep(5);

            }//if recvfrom()
            else{
            int err=errno;
            printf("recv error %s\n",errno);
            }

            sleep(2);


        }

        close(sd);

        return 0;

    }
```

//below is the method which sends response (ACK+SYN)

```
    #define PCKT_LEN 100
    void processBuffer(char buffer1[]);
    int connect1(struct sockaddr_in sa,char buffer[]) {
        printf("Connecting client...!\n");

        char *c=inet_ntoa(sa.sin_addr);
       // processBuffer(buffer);
        int cp=ntohl(sa.sin_port);
        printf("%s  (%d)\n",c,cp);
        struct iphdr *ip1=(struct iphdr *)buffer;
        struct tcphdr *tcp=(struct tcphdr *)buffer;
        sa.sin_port=tcp->source;
        printf("%d %d --------- \n",tcp->source,ntohl(tcp->source));
        printf("%d \n",ntohs(sa.sin_port));
      int sd;

        int one = 1;
        const int *val = &one;

       sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);


        if(sd < 0)
        {
        perror("Connecting --socket() error");
        exit(-1);
        }
        else
        printf("socket()-SOCK_RAW and tcp protocol is OK.\n");
        if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one)) < 0)
        {
        perror("Connecting--setsockopt() error");
        exit(-1);
        }
        else
        printf("Connecting setsockopt() is OK\n");


        if(bind(sd,&sa,sizeof (sa))==0){
        printf("Port Bound\n");
        }
        char b[PCKT_LEN];
        struct iphdr *i=(struct iphdr *)b;
        struct tcphdr *t=(struct tcphdr *)(b+sizeof (struct iphdr));
        ip(ip1,i);
        sync_ack(tcp,t);
        int ret=sendto(sd,&b,sizeof (b),0,&sa,sizeof (sa));
        strerror("Error: ");
     printf("%d\n",errno);

        printf("%d\n",ret);

        return 0;
    }
```

//and this is how I am making ip header

```
      int id=121333;
      struct iphdr * ip(struct iphdr * ip, struct iphdr *temp)
        {
        temp->saddr=ip->daddr;
        temp->daddr=ip->saddr;
        temp->ihl=5;
        temp->version=4;
        temp->tos=0;
        temp->tot_len = sizeof (struct ip) + sizeof (struct tcphdr);
        temp->id=htons(id);id++;
        temp->frag_off = htons(16384);
        temp->ttl = 64;
        temp->protocol=IPPROTO_TCP;
        temp->check=0;
        temp->check = csum ((unsigned short *) temp, temp->tot_len >> 1);
        return temp;
    }
```

//and following is I am making tcp header ACK+SYN

```
      int seq=1105024978; 
      struct tcphdr * sync_ack(struct tcphdr * tcp,struct tcphdr *temp)
        {

        temp->source=htonl(80);
        temp->dest=tcp->source;
        temp->seq=htonl(seq);seq++;
        temp->ack_seq=htonl(ntohl(tcp->seq)+1);
        temp->doff = sizeof(struct tcphdr) / 4;
        temp->fin=0;
        temp->syn=1;
        temp->ack=1;
        temp->th_ack=tcp->seq;
        temp->rst=0;
        temp->psh=0;
        temp->urg=0;
        temp->window=htons ( 14600 );
        temp->check = 0;
        temp->urg_ptr = 0;
        temp->check = csum( (unsigned short*) temp , sizeof (struct tcphdr));

        return temp;
    }
```

Please check the code what wrong. I will handle re-transmission but I am not get in to correct port address with first packet. any help will be appreciated

I am running it on Linux (specifically Debian version 5.9 OS)

I asked a question on this work before.
[DOES router or linux kernel change the tcp headers and ip headers of packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972073/does-router-or-linux-kernel-change-the-tcp-headers-and-ip-headers-of-packets)
i suspect this line

```
  temp->dest=tcp->source;
```

This is wireshark info received at Server .11 is client ip and .14 is server ip. 80 is server port

[image]

[image]

this is wireshark at client
[image]

after iptables changes, syn+ack is sending but client port in received packet at client is different. client port wire shark is showing is `60` as before question update pics

```
 # iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

Comment: If  tcp->source does not match the client port shown by wireshark, please dump out and show the differences in the question

Comment: @stark I have added wire shark capture info

Comment: @stark I am not saying tcp->source doesnt match with actual client port. but it get changed when I assign it like `temp->dest=tcp->source`

Comment: @stark how else I can get the client port at server

Comment: The server trace makes sense.  Client sends from port 44200, next packet is server replying to 442.. (cut off, but maybe the right port).  Client trace is odd. There's a packet recvd on port 60, but no send.  Maybe there is something weird in your network setup?

Comment: @stark I am using virtual machines

Comment: @stark dont u think there is wrong with my code something or maybe kernel is doing some changes.

Comment: @stark its not 442, its 44200

Comment: I wish your first capture photo was just a bit wider, because the response from port 80 has a TCP flag set that begins with "R" which is probably RST.  Just because you are listening on a raw socket doesn't mean that linux won't process the packet.  Since nobody is bound to port 80 (you can't bind a raw socket to a port) it will always return a reset and you will never be able to get a connection set up unless you can prevent the packets going to port 80 to somehow be dropped and not processed by the native protocol stack.  Check out https://netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/.

Comment: @JimD. how about if I access `ring buffer`. it can receive packets. if u tell me something about that. how can I use ring buffer to push packets on to the network by send. if u please let me know: does it make sense. will then it will work?  
   As for the `RST` drop I have changed iptables output chain and now its sending the `SYN + ACK`. but main and only problem is destination port. checked with wireshark. I used this ` # iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to by ring buffer.  If you mean the ring buffer the NIC DMAs frames into kernel memory, you need your code to run in the kernel to access that, or maybe you want something like PACKET_MMAP: kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt.

Comment: Using iptables to drop ALL outbound resets is a short term solution since your user space implementation of TCP will want to send resets.  I would suggest using iptables to route port 80 (or whatever port your user space tcp stack/server is "listening" on) to an NFQueue and read from that.  You can write to a raw socket.

Comment: Regarding the ports, I am suspicious that your VM configuration is using network address translation (NAT), which is not that uncommon.  Use telnet on client vm and netcat on server vm and watch the packets go by with a capture on both VMs.  If the ports are translated but the connection works, then there is a NAT somewhere.  It really shouldn't matter what the source port is at the server as long as it gets properly translated back.  If you were planning on filtering by source port, then you need to figure out what is causing the NAT.